# Context for onOptionsItemSelected in app-wide menu

Tags: java, android, android-studio

This app has just two activities. MainActivity was renamed to SpecialsActivity. The other activity is PizzaActivity. Using the BottomNavigationView, I want to navigate between the two activities. So far, the app opens in SpecialsActivity, and the pizza button does open the PizzaActivity. But then it will not switch back to the SpecialsActivity. I think the issue is related to context. Please help.

SpecialsActivity.java

```
public class SpecialsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_specials);
        Toolbar myToolbar = findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);
    }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.action_specials:
                    Intent specials_intent = new Intent(this, SpecialsActivity.class);
                    startActivity(specials_intent);
                    return true;
                case R.id.action_pizza:
                    Intent pizza_intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PizzaActivity.class);
                    startActivity(pizza_intent);
                    return true;
                default:
                    // Do nothing
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

activity_specials.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="49dp"
            app:itemBackground="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_menu" />
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <activity android:name=".SpecialsActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".PizzaActivity"></activity>
    </application>
```

bottom_menu.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_specials"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_home_black_24dp"
        android:title="Specials"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:onClick="onOptionsItemSelected" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_pizza"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_local_pizza_black_24dp"
        android:title="Pizza"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:onClick="onOptionsItemSelected"/>
</menu>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing

```
Intent pizza_intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PizzaActivity.class);
```

into this

```
Intent pizza_intent = new Intent(this, PizzaActivity.class);
```

Comment: @Randy make sure you have the onOptionsItemSelected method in your pizza activity too.

Comment: This made it work. Thank you. Hope to find a way to make this a global method so I can edit just one.